# Are coherent tunneling and incoherent hopping belong to quantum interference?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, quantum-tunneling

What the accurate definition of quantum interference in molecule or molecules? In some case, there is coherent tunneling in a molecule junction while sometime it is incoherent hopping, or even the combine of them, should all of them belong to quantum interference?

Answer (score 1):

Coherence in molecules [has been demonstrated](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/journal/v2/n4/full/ncomms1263.html) . They prepare large molecules and show they are in a quantum mechanical state, i.e can be described by one wave function with phases that display interference.

> The wave nature of matter is a key ingredient of quantum physics and yet it defies our classical intuition. First proposed by Louis de Broglie a century ago, it has since been confirmed with a variety of particles from electrons up to molecules. Here we demonstrate new high-contrast quantum experiments with large and massive tailor-made organic molecules in a near-field interferometer. Our experiments prove the quantum wave nature and delocalization of compounds composed of up to 430 atoms, with a maximal size of up to 60 Å, masses up to m=6,910 AMU and de Broglie wavelengths down to λdB=h/mv≃1 pm. We show that even complex systems, with more than 1,000 internal degrees of freedom, can be prepared in quantum states that are sufficiently well isolated from their environment to avoid decoherence and to show almost perfect coherence.

Interference in waves and in quantum mechanical probability waves, means the same thing: the phase differences are fixed and thus interference patterns can appear. Interference is *an effect* of the wave nature, it is not the wave nature.

Hopping and tunneling differences are answered in this [question here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57455/tunneling-v-hopping)
. In  a nutshell, tunneling is the quantum mechanical solution that goes through a barrier and retains its phase after going through, so can *show* interference. Hopping electrons lose their phases and thus cannot show interference.

[Here is](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html) how tunneling happens.

[image: tunneling]

All three terms are a result/effect of the wave nature of quantum mechanical states, not of interference.